# Javascript logging sensitive data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, passwords

I am setting up logging that contains passwords received from the user and posting this object to the backend, the password is a key in a JSON object.

e.g,

```
{
    "username": my_username,
    "password": my_password
}
```

I want to capture this object before POSTing but do not want to log the password value. Is there a way to exclude the password value from being logged?

I am creating a JSON skeleton in `constants.js` like this following

constants.js

```
const userDataObj = Object.freeze({
    "username": null,
    "occupation": null,
    "password": null
})

module.exports = userDataObj;
```

then in my `routes.js` POSTing it to the backend.

firemanRoutes.js:

```
import userDataObj from '../../config/constants';
...
//initialize stuff in the constructor and set constants
constructor(socketProvider) {
    super(socketProvider);

    this.userDataObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userDataObj));
    this.userDataObj.occupation = 'fireman';
  }

// get the passphrase and post object 
validate(res, user, passphrase) {
this.userDataObj.passphrase = passphrase;

// want to log object here **without** password
winston.info('Posting object: ' + this.userDataObj);


validateUser.post(user, this.userDataObj).then(() => {
  if (!validateUser.getSuccess()) {
    return super.handleErrors(res);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: well, can we see your code? Which function is responsible for doing that? How does the log is being done?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Added

Comment: winston.info('Posting object: ' + this.userDataObj.username + " " + this.userDataObj.occupation); ........ is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip the `password` property from the object before saving:

```
const safeObject = {
    ...this.userDataObj,
    password: undefined // Or whatever value you want to use, eg "hidden", "removed", etc.
};
winston.info('Posting object: ' + safeObject);
```

This creates a shallow copy and then overwrites the `password` property.

---

This is a "blacklist" approach to deciding what properties are safe to log - IE if you add a new property that shouldn't be logged, you would need to explicitly overwrite it.

---

An alternative would be a "whitelist" approach - ie explicitly saying which properties are safe to log:

```
const safeObject = {
    this.userDataObj.username,
    this.userDataObj.occupation,
    this.userDataObj.passphrase
};
winston.info('Posting object: ' + safeObject);
```

The benefit here is that if you add a new property it will not be logged unless you explicitly say so. I mention this because the `passphrase` property is currently being logged, but I'm not sure if that is intentional or accidental. If it is accidental, then this approach would have prevented this bug.

---

If the spread operator (`...`) is not available, you can get the same behavior with `Object.assign`:

```
const safeObject = Object.assign({}, this.userDataObj);
safeObject.password = undefined;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this at the `winston` level rather than having to delete properties from objects before logging?